# How to Pass Query Answer into Limit Function Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I am attempting to sample 20% of a table in impala. I have heard somewhere that the built in impala sampling function has issues.

Is there a way to pass in a subquery to the impala limit function to sample n percent of the entire table.

I have something like this:

```
select 
* from
table_a
order by rand()
limit
(
select 
round( (count(distinct ids)) *.2,0)
from table_a) 
)
```

The sub query gives me 20% of all records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Impala has specific sampling logic (some databases do).  But you can use window functions:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from table_a
     ) a
where seqnum <= cnt * 0.2;
```